# Drag and drop buffer utility to collect several items then give them to you to drop onto a target

Tags: windows, file-management, user-interface, utility, drag-drop

This monkey patching solution would speed up many workflows.

Say I'm browsing a folder structure in Windows Explorer, selecting things to upload to the browser. The web app doesn't know how to queue uploads so I'd like to **somehow collect the files I want to drop,** then at the end drop them onto the window.

A clipboard manager is a buffer / queue for copied items, this is a buffer / queue for selected / dragged items.

Bad input devices make dragging and dropping risky, and dragging a selection consisting of files from different folders is impossible.

---

Worth looking into, haven't understood yet:

- [AHK-just-me/DoDragDrop](https://github.com/AHK-just-me/DoDragDrop)
- [[COM] Help with the IDropSource and IDropTarget interfaces - AutoHotkey Community](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=8700)

Comment: Do you sometimes need to move (= cut and paste) all content of the "buffer" to another folder? That might be trickier than read-only operations like copy or dropping into a web browser.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul No I was just thinking about the drag and drop operation specifically... a buffer of selected files, a collection of file references. Cutting, pasting, creating shortcuts to files is not a problem.

Comment: "drag and drop" can mean cutting if you hold the control key. "is not a problem" = "is not needed", right?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I'd like the drop to emulate a real drop event perfectly, so if any modifier key is held down it would do that thing. But I'm most interested in the _drop onto program window to open / upload_ interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use **Xplorer2** by [zabkat](https://www.zabkat.com/x2lite.htm). I use the Pro version, but there is a free Lite version as well.

It is a Windows Explorer replacement that provides dual panes for file management and many other advanced features that are incredibly useful but not found in Windows Explorer.

In the case of your question, the Pro version provides a feature called a **scrap container.**

> Manage files from many folders at once 
>   xplorer² has a special kind of window called scrap container where you can place files from many folders and deal with them all at once — like the find files result list, except that you control what goes in (aka virtual folders or playlists). You can save and reload scrap lists, organizing your content regardless of its physical location. You can even browse folders flat, recursively including all their subfolders!

This feature is not available in the free version.

You drag and drop any collection of files and folders into the scrap. Then highlight everything in the scrap, drag and drop onto the web page. I have used this mostly with Google Drive. Works very smoothly.

I have been using dual pane file management since DOS, so I can't live without it. You may only use xplorer2 for this one purpose, or do I like I do and set xplorer2 to completely replace Windows Explorer.

Comment: Would you mind providing a screenshot of the scrap container in action? Thanks!

Comment: Scrap container feature works, pretty nifty, thanks!